# For $p$ prime, how to find the number of primes ending in 3 $ \leqslant p$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

**Example**

Denote $n_{1},n_{3},n_{7},n_{9}$ as the number of primes ending in $1,3,7,9$.

Let $p = 807659729$, where these values are known

$n_{1}=10379490$
$n_{7}=10380409$
$n_{9}=10379783$

Using the [prime counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function) $\pi(p)$

$n_{1}+n_{3}+n_{7}+n_{9} = \pi(p)-2$

$n_{3} = \pi(p)-2 - (n_{1}+n_{7}+n_{9})$

$n_{3} = 41520002 - 2 - (10379490+10380409+10379783)$

$n_{3} = 10380318$

**Question**

Is there a better method to find $n_{3}$?

Comment: There are infinitely many primes ending in $1$. Why is $n_1$ then a finite number? Do you mean the primes less than $p$?

Comment: Where are you using the prime number theorem?  It looks like you are just using some stored numerical value for $\pi(807659729)$.  It's hard to get exact numerical values from the prime number theorem.

Comment: As a general matter:  if you need exact values, you'll have to count them.  If you are ok with estimates, then the prime number theorem lets you estimate the number of primes up to your cutoff and Dirichlet tells you that these will be (roughly) equidistributed amongst the possible classes (as your values illustrate).

Comment: You are not using the Prime Number Theorem, which is an asymptotic for the value of $\pi(x)$. You are using the prime counting function $\pi(x)$. That's completely different.

Comment: @jjagmath Thanks! I meant to say 'prime counting' not 'prime number'. Edited and fixed.

Comment: If the three $n_i$'s are actually given, there is no need to avoid the simple solution (of course it is necessary to consider the exception primes $2$ and $5$ as did in the calculation) and of course there is no better way then (what should be easier than a simple subtraction ?)

Comment: But if the $n_i$'s would not be given, you need to count them (and you even cannot use $\pi(p)$ , if your result must be exact). If you are content with an approximation you can use that , at the long run, the possible prime residues are equally distributed , despite of Chebycheff's bias preferring non-quadratic residues.